# how to parse XML in grails

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-orm

I have object has XML as a string. For example I have a domain which has

```
class person{
    String personId
    String personName
    String personType
    String personDescription
    String personDetailsXML
}
```

I am getting the details and binding to person object. I have to pass this object to another controller which displays the info about each person when he clicks on the profile name. How do i parse the XML string.

I have another domain say eachPerson domian which has

```
class eachPerson{
 String personName
 String personDescription
 Object personDetails
```

I want to match the person name and person description and persondetailsXml.How do I do that and how can I parse personDetailsXML to personDetails object. Please suggest. How i can pass the personInstance as object to action show() in eachPerson controller??

Comment: Will you clarify your question? I'm having trouble grasping the problem.

Comment: PersonDetailsXMl has the values for each person. To be more precise I have a list of persons. When the user selects a person, I have to pass the person detailsXML, which has the details of the particular person selected to each person controller and parse the values in each person controller's show action.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the xml (using introduced in the link in the comment above - or with XmlSlurper). This is pretty straightforward and easy to understand. 
If you have all the data you can use `render(action:'show', controller:'eachPerson', model:[persons:personsData])`. See the grails doc for further details how to use `render`.

This will call the action with the given data. In the show action you can access it with `params.persons`.

Comment: Render would not work because render returns a view. I want to perform some action in controller's show before rendering the view.

Comment: Not directly, it will executes the according `show` closure which itself will render something (gsp, json, ...) - if it returns just a map (it will assume that there is a corresponding `show.gsp` which gets filled with this values.
But you could also use a simple java-like method, if you just want to execute any function...

Answer (score 1):

I'd check this out for starters. Should be pretty straightforward to work from this example.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Reading+XML+using+Groovy%27s+XmlParser.

---

(Upon re-reading, this doesn't entirely answer the question...)